# The term of old thing but still used

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, computing

**tl;dr:** What is preferred term for something that is old but still used today?

My friends and I like to play Minecraft. We built a server to play together and we rented a VPS to run it. But someday the world was too big for VPS to handle, so I restarted the world.

Sometimes I miss playing the old word. So, I decided to play it again on another server. But, I am confused about how to describe this.

My questions is: what is the preferred term for something that is old but still used today?

My choices are:

1. Classic
2. Old
3. Older
4. Retro
5. Last
6. Lasting
7. Endure
8. Enduring
9. Deprecated (I would prefer not to use this)

**N.B.** Maybe this comic illustrates my struggle: [Permanence](https://xkcd.com/910/)

Comment: *Legacy*, perhaps, is what you meant.

Comment: An *oldy but a goody*.

Answer (score 1):

I like "vintage." It seems to indicate something old that has remained 'good' (or gotten better) as time as gone on.

Answer (score 0):

***[Evergreen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evergreen)*** may be an option:

> - Something that remains perennially fresh, interesting, or well liked.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the word you are looking for is antique or antiquated.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antique

> 1. of or belonging to the past; not modern
> 2. dating from a period long ago
> 3. in the tradition, fashion, or style of an earlier period; old-fashioned; antiquated

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antiquated

> 1. continued from, resembling, or adhering to the past; old-fashioned

Answer (score 0):

I like the word "trusty"

My trusty old hammer.